# Unable to install Tensorflow 2.2.0 using pip

Tags: tensorflow, pip, tensorflow2.0

I am using ubuntu 20.04 with python 3.6.5 Anaconda. Previously, I have installed Tensorflow 2.0.0a0 and it was showing in both "pip list" and "conda list" but Now I want to install version 2.2.0 because I am unable to import "stellargraph" as it requires 2.1.x or higher version But when I uninstalled 2.0.0a0 completely and installing Tensorflow 2.2.0 previously, it was not showing in pip list or conda list and so, again when I am trying to install it on terminal using :
`pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl`
as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip), I am getting [this](https://seashells.io/v/zZ6bkaNt) output on terminal.

But it is not installed as I can't see it in pip list and site-packages folder.
[pip list](https://seashells.io/v/ZJFATvzm)

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Run `pip install tensorflow --upgrade` instead.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist, it is not working.

Comment: Why not is it not working?

Comment: I don't know the reason. It is giving [this](https://seashells.io/v/QqWy8bjw)